# Poor indoor cell phone signal

Tags: iphone, blackberry, cellular

Due to the construction materials of an office building, cell phone reception is poor, and it's quite common that calls are dropped.

AT&T, Verizon, and RIM are the typical cell phone networks used (iPhones, Androids, and Blackberries).

Is there a way to boost the signal somehow to provide a better signal? Would I have to attach something to the ethernet network? (there is limited bandwidth, so I would like to avoid this)

Comment: You will need a GSM repeater.

Comment: Why was this closed? It deals with infrastructure.  I did some more digging, and found a similar question that was still open: http://serverfault.com/questions/101885/extending-cell-phone-coverage-and-reception-strength-in-basement-do-cell-phone

Comment: Yep, the closing is ridiculous.

Comment: @ForceFlow, for what it's worth, that question was asked back in 2010 - the ServerFault scope has changed a bit since then so a question allowed back then may not be on-topic now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use either a local GSM/CDMA repeater or enable some sort of service (such as UMA) that can tunnel the connection back to the wireless provider over WiFi instead of cellular.